# User Agent Not Returning Value

Tags: html, user-agent

I am using window.navigator.useragent to detect the user agent of the device when access my website. These device including user mobile phones, tablets, and pc

Some of the devices are able to display the user agent of the device, while some is displaying an empty string

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Browser detection using the user agent string is unreliable.

> ### device detection
>
> Arguably the most common use and misuse of user agent sniffing is to detect if the device is a mobile device. However, people too often overlook what they are really after. People use user agent sniffing to detect if the users' device is touch-friendly and has a small screen so they can optimize their website accordingly. While user agent sniffing can sometimes detect these, not all devices are the same: some mobile devices have big screen sizes, some desktops have a small touchscreen, some people use smart TV's which are an entirely different ballgame altogether, and some people can dynamically change the width and height of their screen by flipping their tablet on its side! So, user agent sniffing is definitely not the way to go.

> ### Feature detection
>
> Feature detection is where you don't try to figure out which browser is rendering your page, but instead, you check to see if the specific feature you need is available.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Comment: I am not using the user agent string to detect the device type or feature, I just want to record the user agent of the device only